# Dropdown list in Zend framework 1

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, datatable, dropdown

I want to implement a dropdown list to select elements from another table and display them using ZEND 1.
I have two tables, products, and categories.
This code shows the list of the elements on the products table.

```
 <?php 
          foreach ($this->products as $product) 
          {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $product->name_product . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $product->category_id . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $product->warehouse_id . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $product->picture . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $product->price . "</td>";
                echo "<td colspan='2'><a href='" . $this->url(array('controller' => 'product', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => 
                $product->id)) . "' type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Edit</a>";
                echo " <a href='" . $this->url(array('controller' => 'product', 'action' => 'delete', 'id' => $product->id)) . "' onclick='return confirm(\"Do you really want to delete this contact?\");' type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
         }
   ?>
```

I want exactly to select the column "name" which is on the table categories and display it on the place of "category_id", in the code above of course.
What is the way to this?

Answer (score 0):

well I've checked Zend 1 there is no prebuilt widget for a drop-down list that's why I
prefer Yii for that but anyway I m going to answer your question so you want to retrieve data from your table and make them on a dropdown list 
and for that, you can do something like that on PHP

```
<select>

            <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>

            <?php endwhile;?>

        </select>
```

### and if you wanna do it in an MVC manner you can write it like that

```
 <select>

            <?php foreach(yourmodel as row)?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row->yourid;?>"><?php echo $row->yourvalue;?></option>

            <?php end;?>

        </select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually how to display all the names of the column name which is in another table called "categorys", on that dropdown list

Comment: well here try to search about join SQL to join your two tables fetch your data and pass it to a variable that will get as result the result of your SQL code with joining the two tables after that do your for each search on zend the syntax of retrieving values of foreign key